# How do I redirect a form after has been submitted?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to upgrade this Drupal 6 code to Drupal 7.

I add a form submission handler to a form, using an implementation of `hook_form_alter()` that executes the following code.

```
array_unshift($form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'], 'MODULE_case_form_pre_submit');
$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULE_case_form_submit';
```

The code for `MODULE_case_form_submit()` is the following.

```
function MODULE_case_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['type'] == 'case_slide') {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'case/' . $form_state['values']['cid'];
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `$form_state['redirect']` looks correct. Check, please, if your handler executed.

Comment: Are you using the code shown in the question, and it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything different between Drupal 6, and Drupal 7, for the code you are showing, which means:

- `$form_state['values']` still contains the values submitted from the users
- `$form_state['redirect']` is still used to redirect the users to a different page

What changes is that the submission buttons for the [node edit form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) are inside `$form['actions']`.

```
  // Add the buttons.
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])), 
    '#value' => t('Save'), 
    '#weight' => 5, 
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
  );
  $form['actions']['preview'] = array(
    '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_DISABLED, 
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Preview'), 
    '#weight' => 10, 
    '#submit' => array('node_form_build_preview'),
  );
  if (!empty($node->nid) && node_access('delete', $node)) {
    $form['actions']['delete'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('Delete'), 
      '#weight' => 15, 
      '#submit' => array('node_form_delete_submit'),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct; maybe you need to ensure:

1. The form submission hander is executed, when the form is submitted
2. The condition checked in the IF statement is true

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using the following code in `hook_node_insert()`. It works now.

```
drupal_goto("content/$title");
```

Comment: Using `drupal_goto` in this hook may cause problems b/c it may prevent other hooks from being invoked that need to do something.

Comment: Actually, in your question you are not saying the code is not working; therefore, I would take there is anything to solve. @MPD is right about `drupal_goto()`; you should not use in that hook, nor in a submission form handler.